# How to solve nonlinear programming problem in Python

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, scipy-optimize-minimize

I want to solve a nonlinear programming problem. The objective function is nonlinear and the constraints are linear. Given a vector `α(dim is n*1)`, I want to find another vector `θ( dim also is n*1)` **make cos(α, θ) minimize**. Meanwhile the `θ` has some constraints. the constraint is `A.dot(θ) < 0`(zero is a column vector)，A dim is `m*n`， `m < n`.

The problem is， `Given α(dim is n*1)`，A dim is `m*n`， `m < n`

```
minimize   cos(α, θ) = α^T.dot(θ) /(|α||θ|)
subject to 
           A.dot(θ) < 0  (zero dim m*1)
```

I have tried to use scipy.optimize.minimize to solve the problem and input the constraints. like

```
scipy.optimize.minimize(method='SLSQP', constraints=cons)
scipy.optimize.minimize(method='COBYLA', constraints=cons)
```

The result of the methods are **depending on the initial value**. I don't know how to get a reasonable initial value so I set initial value is random.  As expected, the method gives a **wrong result**, the results don't meet the constraints.

Comment: this isn't really a Python programming problem at the moment, could you modify the question to include your code that gives the wrong answer?  the closer this is to a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) the more help you're likely to get!

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your inequality constraint

```
def constraint1(A,θ):
    return np.dot(A,θ)
```

The steps are described [optimization with scipy](https://towardsdatascience.com/optimization-with-scipy-and-application-ideas-to-machine-learning-81d39c7938b8)

Then you go for sequential least-square quadratic programming. You will see that a non-convex optimization problem has no mathematical guarantee to be solved.

Comment: I had added the contraints to the algorithm. but it is no use. I konw it can't find global optimum solution. but I only want to get a local optimum solution meet the constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal code solved with a nonlinear programming solver in `gekko`:

```py
import numpy as np
from gekko import GEKKO
g = GEKKO()

# dimensions
m=3; n=4

# constants
A = np.ones((m,n))

# variables
θ = g.Array(g.Var,n,lb=-10,ub=-1e-3)
α = g.Array(g.Var,n,lb=1e-3,ub=10)

# objective
g.Minimize(α.dot(θ))

# constraint
Aθ = A.dot(θ)
g.Equations([x<0 for x in Aθ])

# solve and print solution
g.solve(disp=True)
print(α); print(θ)
```

There are many good nonlinear programming options as discussed in [High Quality Nonlinear Programming Solvers for Python](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/83/is-there-a-high-quality-nonlinear-programming-solver-for-python)